# echo non english word in TideSDK

Tags: tidesdk

I have installed TideSDK 1.3.1 beta, i have a simple php file:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8");
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>TideSDK</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "¡aló";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

but output is:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>TideSDK</title>
</head>
<body>
¡aló</body>
</htm
```

what happen to `</html>` at the end of output.

if i change code to `echo "¡aló ¡aló";`, last line of output change to  `</h`.

if i copy code to apache server,output  is correct.

is there any mistake in my code, or this is a bug?

Comment: Did you double-check that your files are saved with UTF8-encoding?

Comment: Also, you can remove your first three lines of code. You are not on a webserver, so you don't need to set any headers.

Comment: page encoding is UTF-8, and if i remove header output problem still exist.

Comment: edit: if i remove first three lines, problem remain for longer non english word echo. is this a bug?

Comment: I just tried this on Win7 x64 and it worked without a problem.
May you zip your project and upload it somewhere so I could take a look?

Comment: thank u. http://www.mediafire.com/?h8l63xi91scijjk .i havent a real project.i am checking TideSDK for a few days, this a test project with problem,

Comment: You had a encoding problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Your PHP file was "ANSI as UTF8" encoded, which seemed to cause the problem.
After I fixed the file encoding and converted it to UTF8 (i used Notepad++ for this task, which has a easy function for that), it worked fine.

Find the fixed files here: http://d.pr/f/UksA

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/?d6coaobwcmackmt this is my php file converted to utf-8 via notepad++. bottom of notepad++ page shows utf-8 instead of ansi as utf-8 but problem remains. can u please test this? output is incorrect,

Comment: another thing is : your uploaded code works but it differs with my code